# ODBCAD32 keeps removing data source

Tags: database, sqldatasource

I have this issue regarding ODBC that
every time a user logon a computer the data source I configure in odbcad32 keeps removing/missing

I did configure it everyday and its tiring[evosolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXa6v.png) example here is this data source named Evosolution,
how should I fix this issue so that I don't have to configure it every time the users log in from his/her pc
thanks in advance